# The "toujours" in the sentence "Personne n'a toujours tenté ..."

Tags: sens, négation, adverbes

> **Personne n**'a **toujours** tenté de m'escroquer sur la récompense.

"ne ... toujours pas" means "still not / not yet"

"ne ... pas toujours" means "not always"

In this specific sentence, though, the "pas" (which usually serves to distinguish between the two meanings) does not exist on account of the presence of the "personne". So how can I know without relying on the context whether this "toujours" means "still not" or "not always"?

Substituting "encore" would make things simpler, but what about if you insist on using "toujours"?

> **Personne n**'a **encore** tenté de m'escroquer sur la récompense.

Comment: *Personne n'a toujours...* as-tu vu ça quelque part ? Pour moi c'est totalement impossible dans cette phrase. Ce devrait être *personne n'a jamais...*.

Comment: @Laure: Yes, in a subtitle. So the "personne ne" and the "toujours" do not mix well? Merci.

Comment: What sort of subtitle ? if it's youtube they're rubbish. Yes *personne* and *toujours* can mix, depends on context.  *Personne n'a toujours raison*  would be possible,  for example. SO will answer for sure.

Comment: What was the original sentence?

Comment: The first one is the original. Perhaps the writer meant to say "encore" and made an error in a subtitle? Merci.

Comment: But what is the sentence it was translated from? Or do you mean it was also said in French and you're not quite sure what you heard ? I've seen subtitles on the web,  a lot of the time they're nonsense, even when videos and subtitles are in the same language.  And yes, encore would quite fit in this sentence.

Comment: You may say something like "Y'a toujours personne qui veux venir avec moi ?", to emphasis the fact that there should be at least someone who changed his mind after your speech... but indeed, very rare use of "toujours" + "personne"...

Comment: Also, "m'escroquer sur la récompense." sounds odd... what should it mean... very strange subtitle you found here !

Comment: @Random We can make do with this  as getting less than advertised, even if it doesn't sound good, I agree. But indeed that sentence quoted by OP sounds as either machine generated or written by so who doesn't have a good command of French.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly how it was written in the subtitle of a drama. Incidentally, regarding "m'escroquer sur la récompense", is it more natural to say "m'escroquer la récompense" or "m'escroquer de la récompense"? In this context, it means "try to avoid paying the reward as agreed". Merci.

Comment: How can you assert it was written that way? Do you have a copy if this play? A link? Can you post a screenshot? What drama is this? What author? As already stated, *Personne n'a toujours tenté...* is wrong.

Comment: « m’escroquer sur la récompense » is correct. « personne n’a toujours » is incorrect (in this context). It's probably « personne n’a jamais »

Comment: I came across this sentence a while ago in the French subtitle for one of the episodes of the American TV drama *Person of Interest*. I couldn't quickly understand what the sentence wanted to say, so I went on to jot it down on the spot. As unanimously pointed out here, an error must have slipped into the subtitle. Now it all makes sense. Merci.

Comment: Amazing that respondents would beat around the bush about a turn of phrase that is just plain wrong. I had offered the following answer, but as anything that is spot on and straight to the point coming from me, it was deleted: «Personne n'a (encore) jamais tenté de m'escroquer» / "no one has (yet) ever tried to defraud me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I came across this sentence a while ago in the French subtitle for one of the episodes of the American TV drama *Person of Interest*.

I'm going to guess that its almost certainly a mangled translation of the phrase "Nobody has ever tried" or something similar. As everyone has repeatedly pointed out, the result is flat out ungrammatical in French.

The explanation is basically that English *ever* is a [negative polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) (it is overwhelmingly found in sentences featuring grammatical negation), but *toujours* in French is a positive polarity item with an even more restricted set of licensing contexts, meaning that while *ever* can appear in some affirmative contexts<sup>(1)</sup>, it is practically impossible to construct a simple, grammatical  negative sentence with *toujours* (other than when negating *toujours* itself, that is).

It is probably a safe bet that the "translator" was working off a dictionary and knew virtually no French at all, or the subtitles were outright thrown into an automated translator, because practically no competent French speaker could possibly come up with this sentence..

1. e.g. "If I ever [...]", "only ever", the latter which I almost used in the parentheses.